# xcode 6.3 deprecated UIsearchDisplayController, how to silence warning

Tags: swift, deprecated, uisearchdisplaycontroller, xcode6.3

This line has caused compiler Warnings of searchDisplayController deprecation: as of Xcode 6.3 update.

**ISSUE LINE**  `if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView`

IN

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {return self.filteredPlayers.count}
    else {return self.results.count;}
}
```

---

I resolved this warning in other lines similar in format

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
    let scope = self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as! [String]
    self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text, scope: scope[searchOption])
    return true
}
```

by cutting out `Display` and removing `searchDisplayController?` from `let scope = self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles` line, as so

```
func searchController(controller: UISearchController, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
    let scope = self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as! [String]
    self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchBar.text, scope: scope[searchOption])
    return true
}
```

---

**But I can't figure out the correct edit for the ISSUE LINE above.**

```
if tableView == self.searchController!.searchResultsTableView  //could not find member 'searchResultsTableView'
```

and

```
if tableView == self.searchResultsTableView  //ViewController does not have a member named 'searchRsultsTableView'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can't do it from interface builder, but you have to do it from code instead.

[Updating to the iOS 8 Search Controller](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2015/02/16/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html)

Comment: Be aware that the new `UISearchController` does not work on iOS 7.x.